# Proper way to pass multiple object types in to a collection with restriction

Tags: c#, oop

ObjectA
ObjectB
ObjectC
ObjectD

I dont want ObjectD to be permitted in the collection. How do I specify as type safe?

```
   List<Object> SelectObjects
```

Comment: Why would you use List<object> anyway? if you want custom behavior you might want to implement custom collection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make all allowed types implement an interface (e.g. `IAllowedObject`), and use a `List<IAllowedObject>` instead of a `List<Object>`